# ejb with client artifact - runtime dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dependencies

Our company creates an ejb in two artifacts. The impl artifact contains the implementations and the client artifact contains all the interfaces. This means that the impl artifact has a compile dependency on the client artifact.

Now at runtime, the client artifact needs the impl artifact - otherwise the container cannot inject the required objects. This means that an ear needs to contain the impl artifacts for all client artifacts.

Does this mean that the client artifact should have a `runtime` dependency on the impl artifact? Or should these "circular" dependencies be avoided, even if one direction is `compile` and the other is `runtime`?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the client artifact should have a runtime dependency on the impl artifact?

No and there is no dependency (or better should not be). Take a look at the import statements in the client artifact's classes and interfaces and you will see that the client artifact does not depend on implementations.

If the client would depend on the implementation it would violate the dependency inversion principle which is part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.

> Or should these "circular" dependencies be avoided, even if one direction is compile and the other is runtime?

In fact at runtime an implementation is needed, but that is a question of component assembly. One might want to replace the implementation some day or for test reasons. So it wouldn't be a good idea to introduce a maven dependency in the client artifact to the implementation only to make component assembly a little bit easier.

Instead you should declare the implementation dependency in the EAR deployment unit, because the EAR is the assembly of the enterprise application.

**EDIT**

> Our developers complain that making sure that every client has a corresponding impl in the ear is tedious manual work. One looks for all client artifacts in the dependency:list, adds all corresponding impl artifacts, calls dependency:list again, adds again all missing impl artifacts etc.

I think they take the [JEE development roles](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaca.html) description word by word.

> A software developer performs the following tasks to deliver an EAR file containing the Java EE application:
>
> - Assembles EJB JAR and WAR files created in the previous phases into a Java EE application (EAR) file
> - Specifies the deployment descriptor for the Java EE application (optional)
> - Verifies that the contents of the EAR file are well formed and comply with the Java EE specification

Nevertheless the specification also says

> The assembler or deployer can edit the deployment descriptor directly or can use **tools** that correctly add XML tags according to interactive selections.

I would say that the a `ear` pom is an example of an assembly description using a tool.

JF Meier also mentioned

> Some developers write scripts for this process, but then again, after one changes versions of some ejbs, one needs to repeat the process because maybe somewhere deep down in the dependency tree, ejb-clients were erased or added, so additional impls might be necessary.

To me these scripts are the same as the `ear` pom. Maybe more flexible, but at the price of standards and conventions. The fact that they have to update the scripts with every release makes clear that it would be better if these versions are also updated by maven.

Furthermore... Since the ear pom is just a maven artifact, it can be deployed to a repository as well. This is better then private scripts that noone except the author has access to.

I hope these arguments will help you when discussing the deployment strategy with your colleagues.

Comment: I see your point, but the "component assembly" is the difficult point. Our developers complain that making sure that every client has a corresponding impl in the ear is tedious manual work. One looks for all client artifacts in the dependency:list, adds all corresponding impl artifacts, calls dependency:list again, adds again all missing impl artifacts etc.

Comment: Some developers write scripts for this process, but then again, after one changes versions of some ejbs, one needs to repeat the process because maybe somewhere deep down in the dependency tree, ejb-clients were erased or added, so additional impls might be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for you additional discussion. I meant: The ear developers write scripts to _update their pom_. The pom or maven have no mechanism to make sure that every client has a corresponding impl. This has to be ensured by the developer of the ear or the ear will break at runtime.

Comment: So if some ejb-artifact adds an additional dependency to a client, maven will only add that client to the ear. When you start the ear, the impl is missing. How, as the ear developer, should I make sure that every client has an impl without a lot of manual work after every version update?

Comment: I should add that our ears have usually 50-150 artifacts with complicated dependency hierarchies.

Comment: But the ear pom should list the implementations that sould be used as it's dependencies. I mean the ear pom is the description of the final artifact that is deployed. Thus it must declare all the implementations that must be contained. It can ommit the client dependencies since these are referenced by the implementations (transitive dependencies) and will be included by default as well.

Comment: We have a lot of clients with corresponding implementations. Maybe I have a-impl, b-impl and c-impl in my dependencies section. But after an update, c-impl uses d-client. Now I also need to add d-impl to the dependencies section. Furthermore I have to find out if d-impl uses e-client, which would mean that I also need to add e-impl to the dependencies section. Iterate the process...

Comment: Well, I guess this is a question of module and version management and goes beyond this question or what I think is possible to solve via stackoverflow. A face to face meeting would be better, but isn't possible for now. Sadly I have to say that I can't help you further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I need to replace that manual process for the ear developers, and still, runtime dependencies seem to be the best way to do it (despite the problems you mentioned, but exchanging an implementation for another one will rarely happen).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be concerned with the client's implicit dependency upon the implementation because the server will manage that.

The EJB container creates a proxy through which the implementation is invoked, so there is never a direct reference to it from the client.

If you have the pom for the EJB containing:

```
<groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
<artifactId>Q43120825-server</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q43120825-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the EAR file pom containing:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q43120825-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       ... other modules
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>7</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                        <artifactId>Q43120825-server</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>Q43120825-server.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                    ... other modules that might have the API jar as a dependency
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

then this will build a correct EAR file with the API jar in it's `lib` directory.

Comment: I do not really understand the purpose of <ejbModule>. Anyway, my concern was that a given ejb-impl-jar might require another ejb-impl-jar at runtime, but Maven will only detect that it needs the ejb-api-jar at compile time. This means that certain ejb-impl-jars might not be packed into the ear although they are needed at runtime (we have large number of ejb-jars with quite complicated dependency structure).

Comment: The maven-ear-plugin will automatically deduce the need to generate a `<module><ejb>...</ejb></module>` element in the application.xml because it has a dependency with `<type>ejb</type>`. However, because modern Java EE specs required JNDI names to be generated based upon the module name, we hardwire it using the `<bundleFileName>` so that we get `<ejb>Q43120825-server.jar</ejb>` instead of `<ejb>Q43120825-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>`