# How to make sure that every ejb-client has an ejb-impl (in an ear)?

Tags: java, maven

We have a lot of ejb-artifacts that are split into client and impl artifacts like

```
a-client, a-impl, b-client, b-impl, c-client,...
```

If `a` needs to call `b`, we need to add a compile dependency  `a-impl` -> `b-client`. When we run the ear, classes from `b-impl` are injected to actually do the work.

The problem:

To run an ear, we need to make sure that for every client, the corresponding impl artifact is present. When we build the artifact with Maven, this is not guaranteed. If I add `a-impl` to my pom, Maven adds `b-client` to the ear (it is a compile dependency), but it does not add `b-impl` (because there is no static connection). `b-impl` has to be added to the pom as dependency.

The frequently leads to problems because of "forgotten" impl artifacts. Furthermore, there may be abandoned impl artifacts that will never be deleted from the pom. Possible solutions:

1. Add a `runtime` dependency from client to impl. Solves the problem for Maven, but ties the client to the impl. In [ejb with client artifact - runtime dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44209098/927493), people advised against it.
2. Use scripts to update and check the pom to make sure that every client has an impl.
3. Manually check the `dependency:list` before every build to make sure that every client has an impl.

I do not really like any of the possibilities, but the first seems to produce the least hassle. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is an unusual build environment. I don't really understand why the impl's can be selectively present. I guess you can deploy the server software to different environments and those environments can selectively support which clients can connect to it?

Comment: @Gimby No. Every team builds its own ear (around 20 all together). Each of these ears contains a subset of the ejb artifacts. Some ejb artifacts (that are needed by many teams) are present in many ears, some are only in one ear. To be more precise about our architecture: We distinguish sessionFacade and businessObject artifacts. Each sessionFacade-impl is in exactly one ear, but it may reference a number of businessObject-clients. Some of these businessObject artifacts are in nearly all of the ears.

Comment: What about writing a maven plugin which adds the dependency (b-impl) to the ear?

Comment: This would be possible, but the plugin needs to be recursive: b-impl might reference c-client, this requires c-impl, which might reference d-client and e-client and so on...

Comment: Instead of making a plugin that does it automatically, just make a plugin that fail the build if you detect missing dependencies based on your rules. Then if you have continuous integration, which you should have, developers will fix those issues as they appear.

Answer (score -1):

I would create unittests they run the client - then you see on the test phase on the build if everything is working

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how this addresses my problem.

Comment: You avoid to forgett something at buildtime instead of runtime?

Comment: But how do I check in unit tests whether all impl artifacts for the clients are present?

Comment: Depends on your teststrategy? Maybe one Test for each package/lib or for each class? This sounds to me, that you have very volatile ears and maybe you solve your problem with a step back and rethink your package structure or the way you use client / impls. From my point of view, you should not create a fancy recursive solution to add missing dependencies, you should always know what you do, when you add some depenencies at a with the consequences on b. And to avoid misstakes at runntime, you should write testcases for your situation. And btw, downvotes are for wrong answers not for suggestions

Comment: I downvoted because I do not understand how unit tests could solve my problem. I do not even know if unit tests make sense in the context of an ear because without an application server, nothing will work. And I do not know how unit tests address my recursive client/impl problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the structure itself (how the ears are constructed) can not be easily changed because 100+ developers take part in this and 20+ ears are built.

Comment: 'To run an ear, we need to make sure that for every client, the corresponding impl artifact is present.' 1. Check mokito as an example, you not need a full appserver to create a test. 2. Running the client inside that build in the test phase solves exactly your problem... From my point of view.

Comment: But how do I automatically test all clients? I do not know beforehand which clients are present. How do I write the tests then?

Comment: The Test are inside the client project? Sorry, but I'am out here - Just read the basics about Unittests and Mocking...

Comment: Did you mean that I put unit tests into all clients and then start these unit tests when I assemble the ear? I _know_ about unit tests, but I just cannot follow your descriptions